# How to make nftw() faster

Tags: c, unix, nftw

I am working on a directory listing project and I need to capture all the files on the computer and then store them in a queue, which will then be sent off for worker threads to do work on.

Right now I am using [this example code of `nftw()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw):

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static int
display_info(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
             int tflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{
    printf("%-3s %2d %7jd   %-40s %d %s\n",
        (tflag == FTW_D) ?   "d"   : (tflag == FTW_DNR) ? "dnr" :
        (tflag == FTW_DP) ?  "dp"  : (tflag == FTW_F) ?   "f" :
        (tflag == FTW_NS) ?  "ns"  : (tflag == FTW_SL) ?  "sl" :
        (tflag == FTW_SLN) ? "sln" : "???",
        ftwbuf->level, (intmax_t) sb->st_size,
        fpath, ftwbuf->base, fpath + ftwbuf->base);
    return 0;           /* To tell nftw() to continue */
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int flags = 0;

   if (argc > 2 && strchr(argv[2], 'd') != NULL)
        flags |= FTW_DEPTH;
    if (argc > 2 && strchr(argv[2], 'p') != NULL)
        flags |= FTW_PHYS;

   if (nftw((argc < 2) ? "." : argv[1], display_info, 20, flags)
            == -1) {
        perror("nftw");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I have noticed that it starts out very fast and then dies off pretty quick and each 1000 files looped through takes roughly 7 seconds. I am looking for a way to increase the speed for this function.

Comment: How much time takes `find` or `ls -R` on the same directory? [glibc/ftw.c:nftw()](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/io/ftw.c#L539) internally just calls `readdir`, you could call `readdir` yourself. But the usually case is just I/O takes the longest.

Comment: Running find on the root directory '/' completes in less than 2 minutes. The nftw() takes over 10 minutes before I stopped it because it wasn't finished.

Comment: I found the issue. It always happens after I ask a question.... But the issue is adding things to my queue. I removed the queue and it is now working faster than doing a 'find'.

Answer (score 3):

In the page that you linked, there is this explanation for this behavior:

> To avoid using up all of the calling process's file descriptors,
>   *nopenfd* specifies the maximum number of directories that **ftw()** will
>   hold open simultaneously. When the search depth exceeds this, **ftw()**
>   will become slower because directories have to be closed and reopened.
>   **ftw()** uses at most one file descriptor for each level in the directory
>   tree.

Comment: I am posting this question with file descriptor value set to 2000.

Comment: @Doritos That's a clash between a lot and not enough. You should try finding an optimal number for your case. Maybe search up what `find` uses while you're at it.